# Pagination laravel problem to go next page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a pagination in my index page using laravel, like this:

http://localhost/public/?view=empresas when I click next it became http://localhost/public/?page=2 and I think it should be http://localhost/public/?view=empresas&page=2

my code:

```
@if( request()->get('view') === "empresas" )
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Site</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($empresas as $empresa)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $empresa->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $empresa->nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ $empresa->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $empresa->website }}</td>
    </tr>   
        @endforeach
        
    
    <td colspan="4">{{ $empresas->links() }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
@endif

@if( request()->get('view') === "funcionarios" )
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Empresa</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($funcionarios as $funcionario)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $funcionario->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $funcionario->nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ $funcionario->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $funcionario->empresa_id }}</td>
    </tr>   
        @endforeach
        
    <td colspan="4">{{ $funcionarios->links() }}</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
@endif
```

any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values

Comment: I'm new using laravel, so I don't know where to put `$users = User::paginate(15)->withQueryString();` in my code.

Comment: where ever you got `$empresas` or `$funcionarios` from

Comment: I have `$empresas = DB::table('empresas')->paginate(10);` in my controller.

Comment: right and that is what you have to call `withQueryString()` on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
{{ $funcionarios->links() }}
```

To

```
{{ $funcionarios->appends($_GET)->links() }}
```

Because it will appends your query text.

Comment: Why not make use of the [withQueryString()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values) function provided by Laravel?